# Dynamic Form Field Parameters Joomla Backend

Tags: forms, dynamic, joomla, parameters, field

I'm busy writing a custom Contact Us module for Joomla! 
The module is working and all is well but I want to extend the functionality.

What I need to do is add Form Field Parameters Dynamically in the Backend of Joomla, so that the users of my module can add or remove multiple recipients.

Note that this is meant to only be a module and not a component for Joomla!

Any Suggestions on How I might achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, I want the same feature on my component form

Comment: Nope, haven't found a solution to this just yet. Switched to WordPress development. I find it a lot more developer friendly..